# Thread safe enumeration of NSArray

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, nsarray, grand-central-dispatch

Is the following is thread safe?

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *objects;
…
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
{
    for (MyClass *current in weakSelf.objects) {
       current.property = 0.0;
    }
});
```

In particular I am not exactly sure what happens when `self.object` is set to a different NSArray whilst I am enumerating it in the background thread.

Does it continue enumerating the old NSArray?

As long as I am enumerating a NSArray (and not a NSMutableArray) I don't need to @syncronize right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not thread-safe.

First, the property is nonatomic. So, there's no guarantee that the array hasn't already been released (and thus potentially deallocated) by another thread while this thread is still inside the getter method, between the point when its pointer was put into the appropriate register and the time control returned back to the calling code. That is, the method could, from this thread's point of view, return an invalid dangling pointer.

Even if the pointer is still valid by the time you enter the `for` loop, fast enumeration may need to message the array multiple times. Although the `-objects` getter will only be invoked once, I don't think you can be certain that ARC will retain the returned array for you (assuming you're using ARC). If another thread sets the property to refer to a different array, then the setter releases the old array. If that was the last reference, then the array may be deallocated (and that will release all of the contained objects). Ongoing enumeration may then refer to deallocated objects.

Using `@synchronized(self)` around the interior of the block as well as in the setter (or anything which calls the setter) would be enough to make this safe. However, since you're already dispatching the block to a queue, you should consider using a custom queue rather than `@synchronized()` to coordinate operations on the property. Either the queue should be serial or it can be concurrent and you'd have to use barrier tasks for all write operations.

Alternatively, I think it is sufficient to make the property atomic. The documentation says that the getter for an atomic property will do something *like* taking a lock, copying the instance variable to a temporary variable, retain and autorelease it, release the lock, and return the value of the temporary variable.

Comment: I would have thought that updating a pointer in a setter to move from one NSArray to another would be unlikely to cause a problem. The background thread is just reading a memory address and grabbing that NSArray right? Also using atomic is not going to prevent the fast enumeration from accessing a previously deallocated NSArray?

Comment: Rather than using @synchronized(self) would it not make more sense to strongly reference weakSelf.object within the async block? That way the loop can happily continue looping the old NSArray without it being deallocated.

Comment: The setter will release the old array. This can happen while the other thread is inside the getter, after it has copied the pointer to the old array but before it has returned. So, the pointer returned by the getter can be already invalid. Therefore, there's no way anything you do regarding the return value from `weakSelf.objects` can make it safe. If you make the property atomic, the getter will retain and autorelease the array in a manner that's synchronized with the setter such that it's sure to return a pointer that's valid and will remain so for the life of the current autorelease pool.

Comment: OK, and regarding my second point (above in the comments) the following would be just as safe and provide better performance than @synchronized(self) right? __strong NSArray *objects = welf.objects; for (TSPoi *current in objects) {

Comment: You mean in addition to making the property atomic? If it's atomic, I don't think it's necessary to use `@synchronized()` or take special steps to make a strong reference. The getter, by retaining and autoreleasing the array before returning it, has already ensured that it will live for the life of the calling autorelease context. If you don't make the property atomic, then making a separate explicitly strong variable is not sufficient to make it safe. So, no, the code you suggest is not as safe as `@synchronized()`.

Answer (score 2):

Fast enumeration detects if the collection that is being enumerated changes, see e.g. [this nice blog](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html). Moreover, if a block is executed asynchronously, it keeps a reference to `self`, citation from [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1227/blocks-gcd-and-pitfalls-to-avoid): "...from the compiler's perspective, the block that is passed to `dispatch_async` keeps a reference to `self`...".
I think the consequence is that the asynchronously executed fast enumeration will throw an exception when you change the pointer to the collection.

Comment: He's not asking about mutating the array. The array is immutable. He's asking about setting the `objects` property to refer to a different immutable array. Also, he's using a weak reference to self (`weakSelf`).

Comment: From the references cited, I had the impression that changing the pointer to the collection has the same effect as changing the collection itself. Further the docs say that the block keeps a reference to self, and accesses properties using this reference.

Comment: There's no way for the fast enumeration client code (the code the compiler generates for the `for` loop) to know that the `objects` property of some object has changed. It operates on the `NSArray` pointer. Once that's been obtained at the beginning, it no longer cares what happens to that `objects` property (modulo the memory management of the array, as I discussed in my answer). There **is no** reference to `self` inside the block, so `self` is not retained. The docs you cited are for access to instance variables implicitly from `self`. That's not happening here.

Comment: Thanks, Ken, for the clarification, and +1 for your detailed answer!